# Acceptable load time

Tags: testing

I am working on a point of sale (POS vending machine) project which has many images on the screen where the customer is expected to browse almost all of them. Here are my questions:

1. Can you please suggest me test cases for testing load time for images?
2. What is the acceptable load time for these images on screen?
3. Do we have any standards for testing these kind of acceptable load time?

Comment: How long will your users expect to wait. THAT is your "standard".

Comment: Should add, this isn't really a question, hence the short response.

Comment: My users can wait for max of 1 min but we want my application to maintain general standards

Answer (score 1):

"What is an acceptable loading time?" is a very broad question, one that has been studied as a research question for human computer interaction issues. In general the answer depends on:

1. How predictable the loading time is? (does it vary according to time of day, e.g. from 9am to 2am. unpredictable is usually the single most annoying thing about waiting)
2. How good is the feedback to the user? (does it look like it's broken or have a nice progress bar during the waiting? knowing it's nearly there can help ease the pain, even if the loading times are always consistent)
3. Who are the users and what other systems have they used previously? If it was all writing in a book before then waiting 2 minutes for images is going to be positively slow. If you're replacing something that took 3 minutes then it's pretty fast.
4. Ancillary input issues, e.g. does it buffer presses whilst loading and also move items around on the display so people press before it's finished and accidentally press the wrong thing? Does it annoyingly eat input soon after you've started to input it so you have to type/scan it again?

In terms of testing I'm assuming you're not planning on observing users and asking "how hard would you like to hurt this proxy for frustration?" What you can realistically test is how it copes under realistic loads and how accurate the predictions are.

Comment: 1.Doesn’t depend on any timings it takes flat 5-8 min long depending on images  
2.No progress bar it just block complete system on hold 
3.This is the first time we r having images in system and users are general public 
4.There is no chance of pressing wrong things around as display initial screen itself comes with images 
Haha sure, my users are already frustrated and so want to give them a good time  
I want to have good test cases also.. 
Thanks

Comment: 1.Doesn’t depend on any timings it takes flat 5-8 min long depending on images 2.No progress bar it just block complete system on hold 3.This is the first time we r having images in system and users are general public 4.There is no chance of pressing wrong things around as display initial screen itself comes with images Haha sure, my users are already frustrated and so want to give them a good time I want to have good test cases also.. Thanks – TMR